# How is PGCHE by distance learning viewed relative to in-class?

Tags: teaching, online-learning, distance-learning

I've been told by some that online or distance learning PGCHE's (post grad certificate in higher education - basically a certificate in teaching), and distant learning in general, is seen as not serious and that any qualification done over distance learning is disregarded in Europe.

Can anyone from Europe (especially CH) comment on whether distance learning qualifications are 'looked down upon' there?

Comment: Nobody from outside the UK can answer this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the UK many universities require new members of academic staff to obtain a PGCHE. The universities that I am familiar with offer the PGCHE curriculum in house via the School of Education. Since it is presented to new staff as a hoop to jump through, I know of no one outside of university administrators and schools of education that think the PGCHE, in any form, seriously. Further, I have seen many job adverts where a PGCHE is a "desirable" qualification, but never one where it is "essential". During hiring, we briefly consider the presence/absence of a PGCHE, but never more than that.